# Using rails , what 's wrong with this query , it does not return a valid id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

store_id=Store.select(:id).where(user_id:current_user.id).to_a.first

it returns id like that : Store:0x00007f8717546c30

Answer (score 0):

```
Store.select(:id).where(user_id:current_user.id).to_a.first
```

`select` does not return an array of strings or integers for the given column(s), but rather an active record relation containing objects with just the given field:

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select

Your code is then converting that relation to an array, and taking the first object in that array, which is an instance of the Store class. If you want the ID, then try:

```
Store.select(:id).where(user_id:current_user.id).to_a.first.id
```

However, I think you're misunderstanding how to structure the queries. Put the where part first, and then find the ID of the first result:

```
Store.where(user_id: current_user.id).first.id
```

And if there is only 1 store, then:

```
Store.find_by(user_id: current_user.id).id
```

Or...

```
Store.find_by(user: current_user).id
```

or.....

```
current_user.store.id
```

(or `current_user.stores.first.id` if there are many)